# subtract two time strings

Tags: java, android, string, time

I have two string variables that are called clockedin and clockedout. I put them in shared preferences and now I am trying to call them and convert them integers so I can subtract the clockedout hours from the clockedin hours to see how many hours were worked.

```
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b){
    if(b){
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println(c.getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
        TextView clockedin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.clockedin);
        clockedin.setText(formattedDate);






        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("toggleButton", tb.isChecked());
        editor.commit();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2=getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor1= sharedPreferences2.edit();
        editor1.putString("clockedin", formattedDate);
        editor1.commit();
    }
    else {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println(c.getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
        TextView clockedout = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.clockedout);
        clockedout.setText(formattedDate);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("toggleButton", false);
        editor.commit();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2=getSharedPreferences("MyData2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor1= sharedPreferences2.edit();
        editor1.putString("clockedout", clockedout.getText().toString());
        editor1.commit();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1 = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String clockedin =sharedPreferences1.getString("clockedin", DEFAULT);


}}
```

My conversion method:

```
    public void onClickButtonListener2(){
Button button2;
button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calctotal);
button2.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Date date = null;
                Date date2 = null;


                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1 = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String clockedin =sharedPreferences1.getString("clockedin", DEFAULT);

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2 = getSharedPreferences("MyData2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String clockedout =sharedPreferences2.getString("clockedout",DEFAULT);

                DateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
                try {
                    date = outFormat.parse(String.valueOf(clockedout));
                    date2 = outFormat.parse(clockedin);
                }catch ( ParseException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (date2.before(date)){
                    long diffMs = date.getTime() - date2.getTime();
                    long diffSec = diffMs/1000;
                    long min = diffSec/60;
                    double hour = (double)min/60;
                    double hourA = Math.round(hour *100.0)/100.0;
                    TextView totalhours=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalhours);
                    totalhours.setText((int) hourA);

                }

            }
        });
         }
```

My log is attatched[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PBjQ.png)

Comment: Didn't you just ask this about 5 hours ago?

Comment: yeah but now i have the log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

totalhours.setText((int) hourA);

Should be: totalhours.setText(String.valueOf(hourA));
OR
totalhours.setText("" + hourA);

If you call setText with integer, it will look for a string resource with that ID.

Comment: thank you. but now i have another problem. for some reason the sharedpreferences does not work correctly. It is supposed to save the time when button pressed and store that time. However, the changes according to when the user gets on the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you storing the formated date instead of the long value from Calendar.getInstance() ? Just do

```
if(..){
   editor.putLong("dateIn", Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
}
else{
   editor.putLong("dateIn", Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
}
```

and then substract them as longs

```
long dateIn = sharedPreferences.getLong("dateIn", defaultValueIn);
long dateOut = sharedPreferences.getLong("dateOut", defaultValueOut);
long difference = dateOut - dateIn;
int hoursBetween = difference/(1000*60*60)
```

And now you just saved your self two pages of code